# React - Tailwind - DaisyUI Carousel

Tags: reactjs, carousel, tailwind-css, daisyui

I am using the following code sample from DaisyUI for a React Carousel.
While each carousel-item has an ID should the `href` in anchor tags be just IDs?
href="slide2" or need to follow the template as `href="/components/carousel#slide2` ?
Do I need to create a separate component for each carousel-item? the code doesn't look so, but still doesn't work.
Not sure what I am missing

```html
    <div class="w-full carousel">
      <div id="slide1" class="relative w-full pt-20 carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/500/800/300" class="w-full"> 
        <div class="absolute flex justify-between transform -translate-y-1/2 left-5 right-5 top-1/2">
          <a href="/components/carousel#slide4" class="btn btn-circle">❮</a> 
          <a href="/components/carousel#slide2" class="btn btn-circle">❯</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div id="slide2" class="relative w-full pt-20 carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/501/800/300" class="w-full"> 
        <div class="absolute flex justify-between transform -translate-y-1/2 left-5 right-5 top-1/2">
          <a href="/components/carousel#slide1" class="btn btn-circle">❮</a> 
          <a href="/components/carousel#slide3" class="btn btn-circle">❯</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div id="slide3" class="relative w-full pt-20 carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/502/800/300" class="w-full"> 
        <div class="absolute flex justify-between transform -translate-y-1/2 left-5 right-5 top-1/2">
          <a href="/components/carousel#slide2" class="btn btn-circle">❮</a> 
          <a href="/components/carousel#slide4" class="btn btn-circle">❯</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
      <div id="slide4" class="relative w-full pt-20 carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/503/800/300" class="w-full"> 
        <div class="absolute flex justify-between transform -translate-y-1/2 left-5 right-5 top-1/2">
          <a href="/components/carousel#slide3" class="btn btn-circle">❮</a> 
          <a href="/components/carousel#slide1" class="btn btn-circle">❯</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am not answering. cuz I am in the same boat learning DaisyUI and today I want to use the carousel for the 1st time... the HREF should be start with #?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the carousel working by doing this instead:

```
<a href="#slide3" class="btn btn-circle">
```

This would then add the href to the URL: http://localhost:3000/#slide3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).